# Parameters to be passed in HTTP request header connecting web-Application protected by SiteMinder SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, siteminder

I have desktop application that is trying to connect to a web-Application that protected using SiteMinder SSO.
Each time the desktop  application is trying to access the web apllication it is discarded by SiteMinder.

Are there any specific parameters that are to be passed, in the HTTP header request, to a web application protected using SiteMinder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the SMSESSION cookie that is returned by SM to your application (HTTP Client) after the user has successful authenticated is included in every request your application makes.